# Convert a column from StringType to Json (object)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is a sample data

```
val df4 = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("A1",45, "5", 1, 90),
  ("A2",60, "1", 1, 120),
  ("A6", 30, "9", 1, 450),
  ("A7", 89, "7", 1, 333),
  ("A7", 89, "4", 1, 320),
  ("A2",60, "5", 1, 22),
  ("A1",45, "22", 1, 1)
)).toDF("CID","age", "children", "marketplace_id","value")
```

thanks to @Shu for this piece of code

```
val df5 = df4.selectExpr("CID","""to_json(named_struct("id", children)) as item""", "value", "marketplace_id")
```

```
+---+-----------+-----+--------------+
|CID|item       |value|marketplace_id|
+---+-----------+-----+--------------+
|A1 |{"id":"5"} |90   |1             |
|A2 |{"id":"1"} |120  |1             |
|A6 |{"id":"9"} |450  |1             |
|A7 |{"id":"7"} |333  |1             |
|A7 |{"id":"4"} |320  |1             |
|A2 |{"id":"5"} |22   |1             |
|A1 |{"id":"22"}|1    |1             |
+---+-----------+-----+--------------+
```

when you do `df5.dtypes`

```
(CID,StringType), (item,StringType), (value,IntegerType), (marketplace_id,IntegerType)
```

the column item is of string type, is there a way this can be of json/object type(if that is a thing)?

EDIT 1:
I will describe what I am trying to achieve here, the above two steps remains same.

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("CID").orderBy(desc("value"))
val sorted_list = df5.withColumn("item", collect_list("item").over(w)).groupBy("CID").agg(max("item") as "item")
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------------+
|CID|item                     |
+---+-------------------------+
|A6 |[{"id":"9"}]             |
|A2 |[{"id":"1"}, {"id":"5"}] |
|A7 |[{"id":"7"}, {"id":"4"}] |
|A1 |[{"id":"5"}, {"id":"22"}]|
+---+-------------------------+
```

now whatever is inside `[ ]` is a string. which is causing a problem for one of the tools we are using.

Sorry, pardon me I am new to scala, spark if this is a basic question.

Comment: the native spark type is a struct, and there is not a json type.

Comment: is there any work around? i just dont want it to be of StringType.

Comment: As @Lamanus said, there is a special `struct` type used to represent complex objects within the dataframe. What are you trying to achieve with that JSON? Seems like all the data inside is already part of the record so I fail to see the point of having the `item` as JSON

Comment: one of the tools require that column in the form {"items": "[{"id": "value"},{"id": "value2"},{"id": "value3"}]"}

Comment: Have a look at [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please change the question to state the actual problem with input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Store `json` data using `struct` type, check below code.

```
scala> dfa
.withColumn("item_without_json",struct($"cid".as("id")))
.withColumn("item_as_json",to_json($"item_without_json"))
.show(false)

+---+-----------+-----+--------------+-----------------+------------+
|CID|item       |value|marketplace_id|item_without_json|item_as_json|
+---+-----------+-----+--------------+-----------------+------------+
|A1 |{"id":"A1"}|90   |1             |[A1]             |{"id":"A1"} |
|A2 |{"id":"A2"}|120  |1             |[A2]             |{"id":"A2"} |
|A6 |{"id":"A6"}|450  |1             |[A6]             |{"id":"A6"} |
|A7 |{"id":"A7"}|333  |1             |[A7]             |{"id":"A7"} |
|A7 |{"id":"A7"}|320  |1             |[A7]             |{"id":"A7"} |
|A2 |{"id":"A2"}|22   |1             |[A2]             |{"id":"A2"} |
|A1 |{"id":"A1"}|1    |1             |[A1]             |{"id":"A1"} |
+---+-----------+-----+--------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Comment: item_as_json is still StringType.

Comment: spark don't have json data type, instead you can store same data as struct type.. check I have added two columns one is ```item_without_json``` & other one is converted```item_without_json``` column to json ```item_as_json```

Comment: Thank you for your time Srinivas. I will find a work-around or change my approach or as you said will try if i can achieve using struct.

Comment: If you want ```json``` as object, You need to convert ```json``` to spark native data types .. i.e ```struct``` or ```map``` types.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment you made to have the dataset converted to json you would use:

```
df4
  .select(collect_list(struct($"CID".as("id"))).as("items"))
  .write()
  .json(path)
```

The output will look like:

```
{"items":[{"id":"A1"},{"id":"A2"},{"id":"A6"},{"id":"A7"}, ...]}
```

If you need the thing in memory to pass down to a function, instead of `write().json(...)` use `toJSON`